# akka, IOC (DI, guice), and xstream

Tags: java, scala, akka, guice, xstream

I'm looking to bootstrap an akka actor system with some objects provided by guice, and I'm not sure how to do it without the use of icky static providers.

Specifically, I've configured xstream to support @Inject annotations, such that when you're deserializing a document a programmer could add a field to his class in the form

```
private @Inject transient SomeServiceObject someServiceObject;
```

this isn't used all that often, but where it is used its *really* handy.

This allows us to write model objects like

```
public class ComplexModelObject{

    private List<List<Double>> matrix; //my domain has a lot of these.

    //keeps stateful references to things like native fortran libraries (gasp! fortran!!) 
    //and other problematic-to-serialize state 
    //--can be constructed easily by guice though.
    private transient @Inject ComplexMathyThing mathy; 

    public int getRank(){ return matrix.size(); }
    public double getOtherObviousThing(){ return doObviousTransform(matrix); }
    public double getRSigmaMachinaValue(){ mathy.doComplexTransform(matrix); }
}
```

The problem is getting this into an akka actor model. Id like to provide akka with such a serializer, the problem is that the serializer instance --for obvious reasons-- has a dependency on an injector instance, like this:

```
public class AKKAXStreamXMLSerializer extends akka.serialization.JSerializer {

    private final XStream serializer;

    public AKKAXStreamXMLSerializer(Injector injector){
        this.serializer = OurSerializerFactory.buildConfiguredSerializerWith(injector);
    }

    @Override public Object fromBinaryJava(byte[] bytes, Class<?> manifest) {
        return serializer.fromXML(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    }

    @Override public int identifier() {
        return 872391;
    }
    @Override public byte[] toBinary(Object o) {
        return serializer.toXML(o).getBytes();
    }
    @Override public boolean includeManifest() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This means I cant simply give akka a typename in the conf file since it wont know what to do to resolve that constructor argument.

Looking at [akkas serialization documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/serialization.html), they make no mention of programmatically setting the serializer, they only mention configuring it via the conf file. Looking at the akka source code, I cant find any reference to serializer objects or how they're resolved, so it looks like im SOL.

Is there some obvious API I'm missing? Is my best strategy to use static providers to find all this stuff?

---

edit: I've found two interesting prospects:

- there's a demo on how to use guice from activator. The problem with this demo is that it seems largely interested in how to allow guice to create actors for you. This isn't a problem I have, but for anybody reading this, [you can take a look](https://github.com/rocketraman/activator-akka-scala-guice)
- There's a class called [dyanmic access](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/DynamicAccess.scala) that the config-file-parsing code uses to generate its classes. It's got a couple of methods that make it look like this akka's *objenesis* (for lack of a better term, it's all-purpose-factory). Its documented like its a user extension point but one that only very sophisticated users should be using.

*would really appreciate an akka experts thoughts*